# How can I bind an event on an element from another view in backbone

Tags: backbone.js, binding, view, underscore.js, models

The  i'm trying to attach event is from another view

I have two views

- headerView
- contentView

My headerView use a Header model, everytime the model change, i render() my headerView.

Like most of iPhone's app, I use two button in my header for navigation, depending on where you are, images can changes.

This is why when I initialize a random contentView, I can access the model in headerView and change a property.

The last thing I need to do is to create a click event for this button.

I'm trying to bind in my content view (it makes more sense)

```
events: {
   "click .h_left": "newLocation",
}
```

Events aren't firing, it's only the case if I place this events in headerView, is there a recommended clean solution to do so ?

Comment: Can you provide jsfiddle?

Comment: I think it is not necessary, i'll explain a bit more

Comment: Is `.h_left` inside your content view's `el` or the header's?

Comment: it's inside the header

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The whole point of `Backbone.View` is to encapsulate the modifications and event handling of a  DOM subtree into a View class. As such, Backbone doesn't support your scenario.

You have a few options of achieving the same end result.

**The simple (but wrong) way**: Use jQuery to listen to the header's events:

```
var ContentView = Backbone.View.extend({
   initialize: function() {
     $(".h_left").on('click', this.newLocation);
   },

   remove: function() {
     $(".h_left").off('click', this.newLocation);
     Backbone.View.prototype.remove.call(this);
   }
});
```

This breaks the encapsulation of your header element, and tightly couples the content view to the header element's implementation. In other words: spaghetti.

**The correct way**: Use a mediator to pass messages from the header to other views:

```
var HeaderView = Backbone.View.extend({
  events: {
    "click .h_left": "onLeftButtonClick"
  },

  onLeftButtonClick: function() {
    //You can use the root Backbone object as a global event bus
    //Publish a message
    Backbone.trigger('header:leftbutton');
  }
});

var ContentView = Backbone.View.extend({
   initialize: function() {
     //Subscribe to a message. If you use listenTo, the subscription is 
     //automatically cleared when your content view is destroyed.
     this.listenTo(Backbone, 'header:leftbutton', this.newLocation);
   },

   newLocation: function() {
     //..
   }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, don't we need to remove the "listenTo" event for preventing memory leaks when we close this contentView ?

Comment: @KopaxJackHerrauer You don't. `listenTo`ed events are cleaned up when you `remove` the view. Check the documentation at backbonejs.org.

Comment: thanks...i am also new to backbone. helped me a lot. and also learnt new thing. thanks buddy...